# Word that means "to walk around a room" in the context of looking at things

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Not with criminal intent (i.e. case, prowl), but curiosity, as in a museum or in a new friend's house. "Roam" and "stroll" seem more about the movement. Maybe there is no word that implies walking and looking? Example:

He () [around] the museum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Browsed* refers to looking around, at about the pace of *strolled*. It could be used without the preposition *around*: *browsed the museum*.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/browse)
>
> Browse:
>
> to look through a book or magazine without reading everything, or to walk around a shop looking at several things without intending to buy any of them:

Comment: An excellent suggestion, so I have edited it with just one dictionary illustration taken from many.

Comment: @Anton Good addition.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'perambulate':

*walk or travel through or round a place or area, especially for pleasure and in a leisurely way*.